# Add an associated pair to a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array, i tried writing

```
array_push($json['Request']['Header'], "key" => "val");
```

but i received an error. Writing the below works but it adds an array instead of just the key/val

```
array_push($json['Request']['Header'], array("key" => "val"));

..
[0] => Array
        (
            [key] => val
        )

//i would like
...
[key] => val
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not simply write:

```
$json['Request']['Header'] = array();
$json['Request']['Header']['key'] = 'val';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$json['Request']['Header']['key'] = 'val';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the addition operator to append an associative array:

```
$json['Request']['Header'] += array("key" => "val");
```